# Creating ASP.NET MVC Web-based Apps using IBM DB2 where data source is on an AS400/IBM Database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, db2

The firm I am working for is in the process of phasing out RPG programs to access data on an AS400 IBM Midrange server and the ultimate goal is to integrate Web-based solutions for 20 different locations throughout the corporation. I want to come up with the most cost-effective solution and I was thinking about creating ASP.NET MVC apps and going as far as implementing the actual apps on Azure (Not a requirement just an idea).

The major concern I am having is how can I still take advantage of the capabilities and strengths of using an IBM Mainframe to store data while being able to integrate quick and easy ASP.NET MVC apps? It would be nice to create reusable .dlls with all the logic on an IIS server but on the other hand the IBM server is powerful and already contains quality logic it makes it difficult to decide on where to draw the line between database and logic using an n-tier architectural approach.

Currently my manager has been using php on a virtualized Web server on the IBM Midrange server that has Apache which was purchased as an add-on. The problem is there is no architecture to the design ie: no classes or templates which is why I wanted to take an MVC architectural approach, but I could also create a custom MVC with php. Right now we have a virtual server which contains only ajax requests and all php is hard-coded into each html/php file. We also currently have 12 RPG programmers who will eventually retire.

There is currently SQL embedded into the RPG programs which are basically all stored procedures which the sql stored procedures allow RPG and php/ASP.NET to communicate. I may want to someday create a web service that reads UPC bar codes when our client's customers scan products at checkout. A cost benefit analysis will be conducted prior to make final decision, but I would like to start a project plan soon and I was hoping some experienced IBM/RPG programmers who have used DB2 (or some other adapter/pipeline) for web-based solutions that were not created using WebSphere could supply some helpful information. I will eventually edit this question as needed once more input has been given. Maybe there is a better solution and ASP.NET would not be practical such as Apache server w/PHP. I just feel like it would be much easier to create and manage MVC apps but may not be most practical.

Comment: DB2 is fully accessible to the Microsoft platform making MVC an excellent choice for this project.  Some may even say that DB2 is far superior to MSSQL Servers.  The reason is that the AS/400 is about 500 times more powerful than the best PC, and it's DB support has been around much longer with the best I/O in the industry.  One other excellent thing you should know is that DB2 fully supports Entity Framework, so really you can't go wrong!

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response John! So you suggest creating the logic as needed? I was thinking of just designing a Domain driven environment where I can basically create virtual apps as needed under a single domain and create my repositories and what not eventually using JSON and client-side architecture in MVC. I just think MVC is so great. :-)

Comment: Yes, use EF and or a Repository layer for data access and business logic.   People may say EF is slow but that's not true any longer, but also many don't know that you can drop right to the ADO.NET layer to issue queries directly to DB so, in essence you loose nothing.  If you can create EF models from the existing DB2 database you have class objects you can code against immediately.  It literally takes two minutes to generate those classes from any DB2 table!  What sounds like a potential nightmare is really as easy as pie!

Comment: Taking it one step further, if you use strong type model binding in MVC then you can very quickly create Views without typing in anything, just use the View wizard in MVC and point it to the table class EF generated for you!  You can easily morph any entity to a view model using containment tricks and the best part is MVC's Binding Engine parses all the query strings converting them to strong types for you!

Comment: @JohnPeters Do you have an example some were of using entity framework with the iSeries DB2? I have been looking and not finding anything good.

Comment: You shouldn't need any, because to EF the experience is the same as connecting to SQL, simply install the provide Install-Package EntityFramework.IBM.DB2 -Version 6.0.7 (this is the mediator to make DB2 look just like SQL).  Enter the connection string and you're all set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what we currently have set up is that all of the business and database logic is intermingled with rpg programs and sql procedures embedded inside rpg programs using a purchased SQL DB2 Universal Database extension. We have zend server installed on the apache virtual server, and php which resides on this virtual server. Most of the NET.Data macros have been rewritten in php for the current Web application so redoing this application in ASP.NET MVC would not be cost effective.

My next project will be an eCommerce site so I will be proposing to use an IIS Server to manage the ASP.NET MVC Application (HTTPS/SSL). I can integrate this project by using the .NET Provider Windows adapter to access the .NET library and so forth. Currently the security measures aren't great on our current web application but we don't really need to secure it anyways unless we were to add functionality that processes actual transactions.

Eventually I would like to create an ASP.NET MVC application that does handle the actual transactions where I can have the URI point to the ASP.NET application by editing the http.config file on the apache server to the virtual path of the ASP.NET MVC Web App.

The current Web application is so tightly coupled that most of the code is not reusable in the sense, but the RPG programmers did do an excellent job of writing quality code that it makes sense to integrate some of the coding techniques even to call Restful Ajax requests etc.

[image]

**NOTE***
Keep in mind if you are creating a newer ASP.NET App then using ADO.NET and the old ASP.NET Web pages aren't very desirable if you are starting from scratch (Take advantage of the latest and greatest)

The main reason I don't want to stick with the php framework is because I am a .NET junkie, but using a 3rd-party CMS would be just as effective; that is, if you can find one that doesn't use MySql and allows for full customization basically. Also, we are a Windows office so I would like to start incorporating the Microsoft Web stack which could make some of the firm's internal procedures much more flexible. ASP.NET MVC is truly an n-tier architecture and most of the heavy lifting is already predefined, which makes this framework one of my favorites of all.

Answer (score 0):

First off, a IBM POWER Server running IBM i is considered a midrange system.  Mainframes are a different set of hardware and software.

Since you say the RPG logic is useful,  consider taking advantage of [Integrated Web Services for IBM i](https://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/iws/).  It allows you to call ILE RPG and ILE COBOL programs as a web services.

Another option is the open source [XML Service](http://yips.idevcloud.com/wiki/index.php/XMLService/XMLSERVICE).  It appears somebody has already put together a [.NET wrapper](https://xmlservicei.codeplex.com/) for it.

Lastly, you may want to join the [web400](http://lists.midrange.com/mailman/listinfo/web400) midrange mailing list...as you'll find more participation there than here on SO.

Comment: That is correct sir, my apologies. What we have an IBM Midrange server which has been virtualized into three servers with another IBM midrange server that is used as a hot backup .